# Dynamically move UI object in Filemaker

Tags: filemaker

I'm using Filemaker 12 advanced and I need to overlay a UI object on top of an image container object of a map (Google static map). I need to place these objects though script because I'm calculating their positions based on GPS data.

The hard part of converting the GPS distances to pixels I've already got working from this article here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46729/corner-coordinates-of-google-static-map-tile

Now I just need to be able to place some type of marker in the UI dynamically.  I heard UI object properties can't be changed from script, but that was in reference to an older FM version.  Does anybody know whether that's still impossible or not?  Or of any possible workarounds?  Is it completely impossible to modify the image data itself to somehow show a marker?

I tried doing this with a scatter plot but they're aren't enough controls to actually place a point on a per-pixel level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not come across a way to dynamically move elements in FileMaker, so I don't think you'll have much luck there.

The scatter plot is an interesting idea, but I think you'll find the web viewer easiest to work with since you can use data URLs and Javascript.

If you set the URL of the web viewer to "data:text/html," and follow that with an HTML page (optionally including Javascript) you can make a pretty powerful display engine. You can use a similar technique to include graphics in the HTML page, so that you don't need to do any loading from external websites.

For more information about data urls in FileMaker try: http://sixfriedrice.com/wp/filemaker-9-tip9-web-viewers-without-the-web/

Comment: That's a good idea I'll give that a try.  I never thought of using HTML with the downloaded image itself.  Thanks!

Comment: I've got a web viewer working with HTML.  I'm having trouble displaying an image from a container field within the HTML.  Is that hard to do?  I've got an embedded Base64 image in my HTML for the marker that I can move around now, but I'm not sure how I'm going to put that on top of my map image without getting that map image into an img tag somehow.

Comment: If your map image is static you should be able to Base64 encode that in the HTML, too and then put the marker on top of it. If the map image can be different based on the record things get trickier--but I would bet that you could either use FileMaker's web hosting to get the image from yourself or convert it to Base64 with a command line tool.

Comment: Yea basically our iPad app users generate the maps for when they're offline later back in the field, and want to be able to enter GPS coordinates to find themselves on this map.  So yea the background image can't be hard coded.  How would a command line tool help me?  Are you talking about running one from a FM web hosted server?

Comment: I was thinking of a command-line tool to do the Base64 conversion for you. Seems like the sort of thing that would be in a common library somewhere. You might be able to rig up a process using this, though: http://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: Yea but what would run the command line?  Your suggesting running it on a server somewhere and not running it though the device running FM go itself?